# cakephp paginator last record delete error

Tags: cakephp, pagination

Sample here, please check that happens or not

```
<?php                       
        echo $this->Paginator->prev
          ($this->Html->image('prev.png'), array('escape' => false), 
        array(), null, array('class' => 'prev'));
        echo $this->Paginator->counter
          ('Page {:page} of {:pages}, Total Records {:count}');                     
        echo $this->Paginator->next($this->Html->image
          ('next.png'), array('escape' => false), 
            array(), null, array('class' => 'next'));
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this, hope it works

```
public function index() {
    try {
        $paginatedData = $this->Paginator->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
        //get current page
        $page = $this->request->params['named']['page'];
        if( $page > 1 ){
            //redirect to previous page
            $this->redirect( array( "page" => $page-1 ) );
        }else{
            $paginatedData = array(); //no data to paginate so use empty array()
                                      //you will have to check for this in the view and no longer display the pagination links, since they will NOT be defined
        }
    }
}
```